# Nondegenerate bilinear form

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

We say, that mapping bilinear $ \phi $ is nondegenerate if  $\forall \ \ y, \  \phi (x,y)=0\implies x=0$.

Prove, that $\phi$ is nondegenerate $\iff \det(\phi(e_i,e_j))\neq0$.

Could you help me? I don't no how I must do this. 
I'm sorry for my English, is not good.

Comment: Maybe you mean *non*degenerate

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Big Hint: The matrix $\lbrack \phi(e_{i}, e_{j}) \rbrack$ provides a  way to evaluate the form by 
$$\phi(u,v) = u^{T}\lbrack \phi(e_{i}, e_{j}) \rbrack v.$$
This matrix has determinant $0$ if and only if there is some $u$ in the null space of $\lbrack \phi(e_{i}, e_{j}) \rbrack^{T}$; with this vector $u$ held fixed,
$$u^{T} \lbrack \phi(e_{i}, e_{j}) \rbrack v = 0$$
for all $v$ (since $u^{T} \lbrack \phi(e_{i}, e_{j}) \rbrack = 0$).